# Restofire - How to pass parameters in a request

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I was creating a service with Restofire but i am not able to pass parameters in the request.

This is how i am calling the service but it shows me that `Cannot assign to property: ‘parameters’ is get-only property`

```
let service = UserPUTService()
service.parameters = user
service.executeRequest() {
    if $0.result.error == nil {
        self.saveUser($0.result.value!)
    } else {
        self.showError($0.result.error!)
    }
}
```

Here is the service class i have created.

```
import Restofire
import enum Alamofire.Method

struct UserPOSTService: Requestable {

    var method: Method = .POST
    var path: String = "user"

}
```

Comment: we need more detail about your question.